# Generics of SuperClass

Tags: java, generics, spring-webflux

I'm trying to using generics with the reactive webclient, so far I've create a class that holds the webClient and some methods

```
    public class CustomWebClient<T> {
            
    private final WebClient webClient;
        
            public CustomWebClient(WebClient.Builder builder, ClientProperties properties) {
                String rootUrl = properties.getHttp().getRootUrl();
                webClient = builder
                        .baseUrl(rootUrl)
                        .defaultHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
                        .defaultHeaders(httpHeaders -> httpHeaders.setAll(properties.getHeaders()))
                        .build();
            }

     public ​Mono<ResponseEntity<T>> setRequest(final String uri,
                                               ​final HttpMethod httpMethod,
                                               ​final Class<T> classToMap) {
     WebClient.RequestHeadersSpec<?> requestHeadersSpec = webClient.method(httpMethod).uri(uri);
     ​WebClient.ResponseSpec responseSpec = setRetrievingOptions(requestHeadersSpec);
       ​return setEntity(responseSpec, classToMap);
   
  }  

private WebClient.ResponseSpec setRetrievingOptions(final WebClient.RequestHeadersSpec<?> requestHeadersSpec) {
    return requestHeadersSpec.retrieve()
            .onStatus(HttpStatus::is4xxClientError,
                    clientResponse -> Mono.error(new ResponseStatusException(clientResponse.statusCode(), NOT_FOUND_MSG)))
            .onStatus(HttpStatus::is5xxServerError,
                    clientResponse -> Mono.error(new ResponseStatusException(clientResponse.statusCode(), INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR_MSG)));
}

private Mono<ResponseEntity<T>> setEntity(final WebClient.ResponseSpec responseSpec, Class<T> classToMap) {
    return responseSpec.toEntity(classToMap);
}
 }
```

then I inject the CustomWebClient into another class which is a service

```
      public class ABCServiceImpl implements ABCService {
    
         private final CustomWebClient<? extends BaseResponse> customClient;
        
         private Mono<PageResponse> invokeGetPageFromABC(final String storeId, final String site, final MultiValueMap<String, String> queryParams) {
          Mono<ResponseEntity<PageResult>> responseEntityMono = customClient.setRequest(String.format(PAGE_ENDPOINT, site), HttpMethod.GET, queryParams, PageResult.class);
    
      return responseEntityMono.map(content ->
                    new ContentResponse(content.getStatusCode(), customWebClient.SUCCESS_MSG, createContent(content.getBody())));
        }

    private ContentDTO createContent(ContentResult contentResult){
        return Optional.ofNullable(contentResult)
                .filter(c -> Objects.nonNull(c.getContent()))
                .map(ContentResult::getContent)
                .orElse(new ContentDTO());
    }
}
```

at this point a get a compile time error which is

```
Required type: Class <capture of ? extends BaseResponse>
Provided: Class <ContentResult>
```

Here is the object I'm passing

```
public class ContentResult extends BaseResponse {

    private ContentDTO content;
}
```

Since I'm new with generics probably there is something I'm missing or I didn't fully understand. Any clue about what could be the problem?

Honestly I've expected to work given the fact that I've actually specified the super class while injecting the customWebClient.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: How are you doing the injection?

"then I inject the CustomWebClient into another class which is a service"

Comment: and you post the ​setEntity(responseSpec, classToMap)

Comment: I also notice you've got:

Mono<ResponseEntity<PageResult>> responseEntityMono =
                customClient.setRequest(String.format(PAGE_ENDPOINT, site), HttpMethod.GET, queryParams, PageResult.class);
which according to your parameterization, seems to require that the parameterized type be PageResult;

Comment: @AlexanderKatsenelenbogen sorry for the messy code. Now it should be okay.

Comment: Can you whittle the code down to the base question?  Right now it has too much extraneous lines that have nothing to do with generics.  Thanks.

Comment: @Gray You are right, but I just wanted to provide an overview of the whole content. The main issue is related to this line private final : CustomWebClient<? extends BaseResponse> customClient; where I declare a generic content inside the CustomWebClient, then I got his other line : customClient.setRequest(String.format(PAGE_ENDPOINT, site), HttpMethod.GET, queryParams, PageResult.class);
 Where I get a compile error, saying there's no match between the two types even though the second one extends the first one.

Comment: If you whittle it down @Maxuel, often you can figure it out.  The more characters in your post the more confusing.  See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @Maxuel Again --- You have at least 1 problem from what I can make out: PageResult.class is being passed under the assumption that the customClient has parameterized type "PageResult"; meanwhile you've declared it with parameterized type "? extends BaseResponse"

"public ​Mono<ResponseEntity<T>> setRequest(final String uri,
                                               ​final HttpMethod httpMethod,
                                               ​final Class<T> classToMap) " -> parameterized type is "T"

" public class CustomWebClient<T>" parameterized type is also T

Comment: Agree with @Gray

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've combed through this, and I think I understand what you're trying to do. I recommend not using the wildcard ("?") in this way. When you call `customClient.setRequest(..)`, the compiler can't figure out what version of customClient you have (i.e. what subclass of BaseResponse), so it throws an error when you try to pass in the parameterized type Class object (which looks to be PageResult.class)

You could fix this by turning `ABCServiceImpl` into a parameterized class i.e.
`ABCServiceImpl<T extends BaseResponse>` with a field property of `private final CustomWebClient<T extends BaseResponse> customClient`;

But I still wouldn't do that either, because it looks like your custom client does not need to be a parameterized type at all!

So I'd recommend this:

1. Remove the parameterized type from CustomWebClient. (i.e. `public class CustomWebClient` instead of `public class CustomWebClient<T>`)
2. Make the `public ​Mono<ResponseEntity<T>> setRequest(..)` method a parameterized method instead: `public <T> ​Mono<ResponseEntity<T>> setRequest(..)`
3. Call the method on customWebClient like so:

   `customWebClient.<ContentResult>setRequest(ContentResult.class, ...etc);`